# Как мне найти базовые виды конфигурации в Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть такая конфигурация(просто для примера):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SomeInterceptor someInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(someInterceptor);
    }

}
```

Тут для указания конкретной настройки используется наследование от класса `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. Где мне найти другие классы от которых можно наследоваться и настраивать под каждый конкретный случай мое приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс, что вы указали - оффициально [deprecated](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html).

Список интерфейсов для инициализации веб приложения можно посмотреть [здесь](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet).